# Vue Router - build from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-router

I'm quite new to Vue.js. I'm used to vanilla JavaScript.
I need to be able to generate route paths from a JSON file.
How can I achieve it?

**EDIT**

For example, say this is my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Product 1",
    "url": "product-1",
  },
  {
    "name": "Product 2",
    "url": "product-2",
  }
]
```

I basically need Vue Router to redirect `URL/product-1` to Product 1's component (which will be `<Product-1></Product-1>`), and `URL/product-2` to Product 2's component (`<Product-2></Product-2>`)

Comment: what about a normal `map` function to match the API?

Comment: As I said, I'm new to Vue. How can I apply the `.map()` thingy to Vue Router?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your component's name is `name` in the object, we need to match your structure to [Vue Router API](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route).
Thus, we can do as follows:

```js
const myRoutes = [
  {
    "name": "Product 1",
    "url": "product-1",
  },
  {
    "name": "Product 2",
    "url": "product-2",
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: myRouters
          .map(({name, url})=>({component: name, path: `/${url}`)),
})
```

Comment: Sorry for the messed up link. I'm high af. @avi12

Comment: This answer doesn't fully satisfy me, as I do need to link the `routers:` to an external file. Except, using `fetch()` will give a Promise at the end, so I need to find a way to make the `export default` to get a `Router` with all the routes, as an array

Comment: how about lazy-loading all your components then defining routes?

Comment: I guess I can test this. Any idea what's the best technique to do so?

Comment: Whichever you like. Personally, I use Webpack chunk loading